# Lab 9.3 Issues (Yes, I found out what was wrong with 9.1)

Tags: java, arrays, double, sqrt

I completed 9.1 and 9.2. Now, I think the answer isn't something that simple. Here are the instructions:

> The standard deviation of a set of numbers is a measure of the spread of their values. It is defined as the square root of the average of the squared differences between each number and the mean. To calculate the standard deviation of the numbers stored in data:
>
> Calculate the mean of the numbers.
>
> For each number, subtract it from the mean and square the result.
>
> Find the mean of the numbers calculated in step 2.
>
> Find the square root of the result of step 3. This is the standard deviation.
>   Write code to calculate the standard deviation of the numbers in data and store the result in the double sd.
>
> To find the square root of a non-negative double d, use the expression
>
> `double s = Math.sqrt( d );`

Here's my code:

```
double[] data = {  }; 
double sd; 
double sum = 0; 
double mean = 0;
double sd = 0;
runProgram = true;

for (int = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sum += data[i];
    mean = sum/(data.length - 1);
    mean = data[i];
    mean *= mean;
}

while (runProgram == true) 
    sd += Math.sqrt(mean);
```

I really don't see what I'm doing wrong. Any advice will be tried.

Comment: Shouldn't the `sqrt()` be outside the `for`?!

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calculating the standard deviation `sd` whilst the mean is changing.  You should calculate the mean for the whole data set first and then calculate the standard deviation using the final value of `mean`.

Also, you should only be square rooting the sum of all the variances and not calculating the square root each time.

Comment: Thanks, I had to rewrite my code due to an Internet disconnection. Here's what my code looks like now. It now has no result, as before I got the result of 3.0 or 5.0:

    double[] data = { 1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0 }; 
    double sd; 
    runProgram = true; 
    double sum = 0;
    double mean = 0;
    sd = 0;
 
    for (int = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        sum += data[i];
        mean = sum/(data.length - 1);
        mean = data[i];
        mean *= mean;
    }
 
    while (runProgram == true) 
        sd += Math.sqrt(mean);

Answer (score 0):

You've got it all messed up. The explanation seems to be pretty good but the implementation seems to have gone wrong. You are calculating the mean on the run (i.e) while calculating your StandardDeviation, which isn't right. You need to calculate the mean prior to calculating your SD, as in your case, the mean is changing fo

You need to understand the formula properly.

StandardDeviation is the `SquareRoot( (sum(square(number-mean))/n) )`.

```
// Calculate the mean first
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sum += data[i];
}
mean = sum / data.length;

sum = 0; // Re-using sum variable
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    double diff = data[i] - mean;
    diff = Math.pow(diff, 2);
    sum+=diff;
}

double variance = sum / data.length; // calculate the variance
sd = Math.sqrt(variance); // Standard deviation is the square root of variance
```

Comment: I tried your code. I'm getting this error with this part of my code:



for (int = 0; i < data.length; i++) {




It says "error: not a statement"

Comment: where is the `i`? it should be `for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {`